# Can a dive attack be made when you would charge as part of an effect?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle, charge

The Battle Leader's Charge maneuver says you make a charge as part of the maneuver.

If a character has wings and is able to do a dive attack, can a dive attack (which "works as a charge") be done in place of a chage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ordinarily replace one action with another action that "works like" that action. A charge is one specific type of action, not a class of actions that all behave in similar ways. <strike>In other words, charge and dive attack share similar mechanics, but they are not interchangeable in the RAW.</strike>

<strike>The Battle Leader's Charge ability specifically states that you may perform a charge, and not a more generic term such as "you can use a charge-like attack", which would allow GM interpretation for additional maneuvers that share charge mechanics, but are not actually a charge (either core material or any additional material as might be available).</strike>

### Edit

Looking further into this, there is a clarification to the rules that actually does specify such an attack as a "diving charge," which ergo, does mean the attack would be compatible with Battle Leader's Charge:

> Charge
>
> Flying creatures can use the charge action. A flying charge must be in straight line and most cover at least 10 feet (2 squares). A flyer can charge while diving, but not while gaining more than 5 feet altitude (unless the flyer has perfect maneuverability and can climb without losing speed).
>
> If a flyer makes a diving charge of at least 30 feet (6 squares) and also loses 10 feet of altitude or more, it can attack only with a claw or with a piercing or slashing weapon. These attacks, however, deal double damage. --[Rules of the Game, All About Movement, Part 5](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112013751/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20040706a).

(Original spelling preserved.)

I've left the original answer above, because it's applicable in other contexts, but the Rules of the Game quote definitely allows a dive attack (assuming you do fly at least 30' and descend at least 10') for double damage in this case, and you can also use a normal charge while in the air (and still gain the +10 damage).

It's exceptionally unfortunate that the core books (and even the online reference material) haven't been updated with these clarifications that I could tell.

Comment: I thought dive attacks were supposed to count as a charge for literally everything. It makes sense, since you are charging, but using gravity in your favor.

Comment: WotC has never been accused of always having the best wording in their books. This doesn't "work like" it "works EXACTLY like" a charge with the few noted exeptions. That slight difference in wording I think makes a huge difference In reading.

Comment: It obviously doesn't work EXACTLY like a charge because it has other restrictions. The question here is if it COUNTS as a charge.

Comment: I was curious, so I went about looking for errata. It was non-trivial to find, but I think that this sufficiently clarifies the situation.

Comment: +1 for corrections. Also, @Jean-LucNacifCoelho, I was quoting the SRD saying "exactly" & stated with the few noted exceptions (mentioned in the dive section of SRD)

Comment: @Ben-Jamin The apparent confusion comes from the d20 SRD under [Special Abilities > Fly](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#fly): "A dive attack **works just like a charge**, but the diving creature..."

Comment: SRD is heavily outdated